# AnAl - weird rotating

Tags: lua, love2d

I am totally new to programming.  I've tested how to script an other things like that... but I tried to use animations in my "game". I used the "AnAl" library. All worked good. But then where I liked to use "moving" (or how it's called ;P) the animations doesn't worked and the character rotated. I don't know what I need to do...
And I used the Lua language,  btw.

```
require ("AnAl") 

function love.load()
    -- Shortcuts
    lg = love.graphics
    lkid = love.keyboard.isDown

    local img = lg.newImage ("img.png")
    anim = newAnimation(img, 100, 100, 0.1,5,0)
    image = { 
        x = 250,
        y = 150,
        rotation = math.rad (0),
        moveSpeed = 200
    }
end

function love.draw()
    anim:draw(figur, image.x, image.y, image.rotaion, 0.5, 0.5) 
end

function love.update(dt)            
    if lkid("w") then image.y = image.y - image.moveSpeed * dt end
    if lkid("s") then image.y = image.y + image.moveSpeed * dt end
    if lkid("a") then image.x = image.x - image.moveSpeed * dt end
    if lkid("d") then image.x = image.x + image.moveSpeed * dt end      
    anim:update(dt)     
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what figur refers to in your code.

The arguments to anim:draw should be x, y, rotation, scalex, scaley. Since you have added figur before the arguments for some reason, you are setting the rotation to be the y position.

```
anim:draw(image.x, image.y, image.rotation, 0.5, 0.5)
```